# Get unique user ID for a webapp from MongoDB's ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, hostname

I need to get a unique user ID identifying a user for a voice recording web app. In order to do this with minimum additional requirements, I am trying to use MongoDB's ObjectID to get this done. According to the official documentation, ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

The ObjectID 3 byte machine field is the first three bytes of the (md5) hash of the machine host name according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924701/how-machine-id-host-name-is-mapped-demapped-to-3-byte-in-object-id) answer. So shouldn't this be unique for a given machine?

However, the machine identifier does not seem to be what I thought it is.

```
--From Laptop--
56316c85 b47e28 f61a6 2b931
56316c89 b47e28 f61a6 2b934
--From a phone--
56316dc9 d75b48 ce1c4 9f2b3
56316dcb d75b48 ce1c4 9f2b4
--From the same Laptop--
56316f47 d75b48 ce1c4 9f2bd
56316f7e d75b48 ce1c4 9f2be
```

Can someone help me understand this? This is the same MongoDB being hosted locally (on the laptop) and being accessed once from a Phone's browser (which is on the same network) and once on the laptop.

Comment: Where are these documents being generated? That is the key piece of information - the machine ID, process ID is from the machine that generates the ObjectID, which is usually done by the driver. However, if you explicitly do an insert without an _id, then it will be generated by the MongoDB server instead

Comment: The documents are being generated on the server-side i.e. on the same machine. So that means the Machine IDs' are not indicators of unique users who use the app.

Comment: Why are the Machine IDs' different for the examples above? Is the md5sum taking into consideration something else as well other than the Host name?